# making Jquery Swap Image plugin target a new hyperlink

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, hyperlink

I'm using the [Swap Image plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-swapimage/), particularly Disjoint Rollovers 2.

[Here's the live page](http://www.subrb.com/concept/about-us.html)

I'm trying to make the target image (the big image on the left) a new hyperlink depending on the image that is loaded there.  The code I'm using is

```
<img class="swapImageDisjoint { sin: ['#main:images/big-head-4.jpg'], sout: ['#main:main:images/blank-slate.jpg'] }" src="images/head-1.jpg" alt="" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need Swap Image to do what you want.  You can do all of it with a single click method.  I put a stripped-down example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3ENWq/

(In this example, I used the img urls as the link url, but they obviously don't have to be the same)

I simply added some extra attributes to your small images called `swapimg` and `swapurl`.  I used the click function to load these into the main image and a mainlink href that I added.  I also tacked on an `each()` to preload all of the large images if you so desire.

```
$('.swapImage').click( function() {

   $('#main').attr('src', $(this).attr('swapimg'));
   $('#mainlink').attr('href', $(this).attr('swapurl'));

}).each( function() {

   var preloadImg = new Image();
   preloadImg.url = $(this).attr('swapimg');

});
```

If you don't want the extra attributes, you can do it with metadata like the swap image plugin does.  I can post an example of that if you want it.

Comment: No problem!  I updated my example to preload the images as well if that's what you want.